# How to construct an ARMA model MA 1 in excel?

Tags: time-series, arima, excel, moving-average

All,

I understand how to construct an AR1 ARMA model in excel, which is taking the time series and lagging it by 1 period then constructing a regression model (minus the first period) of that but I don't know how to create an MA 1 ARMA model in excel.    Can anyone share a simple example of how to do it?

Comment: Have you found an answer for your question? I have the same question. This is the only relevant information which I have found so far: https://www.real-statistics.com/time-series-analysis/moving-average-processes/ma-coefficients-acf/ https://www.real-statistics.com/time-series-analysis/moving-average-processes/calculating-ma-coefficients-solver/ I have not tested it myself.

Comment: I haven't.   I hope someone can share.

Comment: Please see my updated response.

Comment: Ok.  Thank you so much.